# Kali VM not pinging Windows 7 VM but vice versa is possible

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, ping, kali-linux

I have installed Kali and Windows 7 VM on Virtual Oracle Box. Its pinging fine from Windows to kali but its not pinging from kali to Windows VM.

Both network are on Bridged Connection.

Kali IP address: 192.168.1.103
Windows 7 IP : 192.168.1.109

No error its just sending packet but not receiving any reply.

Let me know what should I do to resolve this issue.

Comment: You know, that by default in Windows 7 the firewall is active and it blocks the ping?

Comment: Please check "n8te" answer on following thread:
https://superuser.com/questions/1214547/unable-to-ping-from-vms-to-host-machine.

Comment: Please check **n8te's** answer on following thread https://superuser.com/questions/1214547/unable-to-ping-from-vms-to-host-machine

Answer (score 1):

1. Open up the Windows Firewall from within the Control Panel or search for it.
2. Click Advanced Settings on the left.
3. From the left pane of the resulting window, click Inbound Rules.
4. In the right pane, find the rules titled File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In).
5. Right-click each rule and choose Enable Rule.

Answer (score 0):

First turn off the firewall of host machine (it may help) and set `ip_forward=1`

For setting `ip_forward=1`, you have to do `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` or `echo 1 < /proc/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue with Windows and Kali VMs on NAT. Resolved it through firewall settings.

Windows Firewall>Advanced settings>Inbound rules:

**Enable** '*Change Virtual Machine Monitoring (Echo request- ICMPv4-In)*'.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are on NAT Network on both the VMs if you want both VM's to access internet and VM intranet. Before being on NAT Network Create your own NAT NETWORK IN Virtual Box as default can cause some problems.

Once you created your own NAT network with a DHCP range ex - 10.1.2.0 then switch all the VM's you want to ping with.

For windows OS make sure that you turn of the Firewall.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-microsoft-defender-firewall-on-or-off-ec0844f7-aebd-0583-67fe-601ecf5d774f // Microsoft support Link

[Turn Windows Defender Private firewall Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er8tq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er8tq.png)