# Unable to ping from VM's to host machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, centos, virtualization, vmware

I have started 2 VM's in VMware Workstation with the network connection as *bridged*.

Let's say the IP's of my VM's are 192.168.1.3 and 192.168.1.4.From these VM's I'm able to ping the internet e.g.: Google. From my host system (where VMware is running) I can ping to these VM's also. Let's say my host IP is 192.168.1.2.

However, from the VM's I'm not able to ping my host IP, there is no reponse or output but when I stop the ping using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it gives the information below.

```
----192.168.1.2 ping statistics----
704 packets transmitted, 0 received,100% packet loss,time 704557ms
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: My host is Windows 7 and the VM's are CentOS 7 Minimal

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**In Windows 7 (also the case in Windows 8/10) by default the Windows Firewall is set to block ping requests.** To be able to ping your host from one of your virtual machines--or anywhere else on your LAN, for that matter--you will need to either disable the firewall or enable the firewall rule that allows ping requests. To set the firewall rule to allow ping requests in Windows 7 do the following:

1. Click on the **Start Menu**
2. Go to **Control Panel**
3. Open **Windows Firewall**
4. Open **Advanced Settings**
5. Select **Inbound Rules** over in the left window pane
6. In the right window pane scroll down to **File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)**. You will see two of these listed. The first one for enabling this rule to for a domain profile. The second one is for enabling this rule for public/private profile. Unless your PC is on a domain, select the second of these two rules.
7. Right click your mouse on **File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In) Profile: Private, Public** and select **Enable Rule**.
   --You will now be able to ping your host from either of your virtual machines.

[image]

Comment: wow it worked...thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your host is blocking incoming ICMP traffic, including ping. Try pinging from another device outside of your VMs to the host.